# Opening ports on macOS High Serra

Tags: terminal, network, firewall

Ok so I am having a time trying to get this to work. 
I have a program that needs to push to another program on port 8080. However I can't seem to get that port to respond.

I have checked my router (RBS50) to make sure nothing is blocking. I have even put the computer in the DMZ to make sure everything is working on that side. However even in the DMZ I can't get the programs to respond to each other. I figure it must be something locally with my computer. If I try and hit the port from another machine on the same network I still can't hit the open port.

I have tried various commands via terminal to see if I can get it to work and none have worked so far.

Running   `lsof -Pn -i4 | grep :8080`
Gives me the result of

```
Program Name   580 Username    9u  IPv4 0xb2e9d1619d08cbdf      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)
```

When I run `nc -l 8080`
I get the results

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: computer.local:8080
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.1 Safari/605.1.15
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

When trying to hit the open port from a different computer.

I do not have a firewall turned on via System Preferences.

I am at my wits end here. Any support or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of application is listening on port 8080? Also, please check your input/output examples, right now they are hard to read.

Comment: @nohillside It is not uncommon to run a (temporary or experimental) web server on port 8080, since the normal http port is 80, and processes not running with uid 0 cannot bind to ports < 1024.

Comment: That’s totally fine. But you state that you want to push something to a program on 8080 and this doesn‘t sound like a webserver. Anyway, basically you are asking why you can reach 8080 on localhost but not from any other computer on the same network, right? Do you get an error message on the other computer? Can you ping the computer running the webserver?

Comment: `TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 (LISTEN)` — 127.0.0.1 is localhost. IOW, the listening socket is not bound to interfaces that are connected to real networks. Sockets that are bound to all networks would show up with wildcard `0.0.0.0` address instead.

Comment: This statement is confusing:  *I have a program that needs to push to another program on port 8080*  So, the problem can be twofold....1) The program isn't pushing the other program to listen on 8080 and/or 2), the program that is supposed to be listening, isn't.  Can you please clarify as to what's supposed to happen and what your expected/desired results are supposed to be?  Maybe even give us the names of said programs?